# How to get the value from a slider in jQuery Mobile 1.4?

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I get the value from a slider when a user drags the slider? What event is being fired?

Answer (score 2):

The slider provides a stop event. This triggers at the end of a drag. From the [jQuery site](http://api.jquerymobile.com/slider/#event-stop):

> Initialize the slider with the stop callback specified:

```js
$( ".selector" ).slider({
  stop: function( event, ui ) {}
});
```

> Bind an event listener to the slidestop event:

```
$( ".selector" ).on( "slidestop", function( event, ui ) {} );
```

If you want the changing value while dragging, use the regular change event on the input.